# How to print response that returns from a web service

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I'am new at using web services and trying to understand their structure, how they works etc. I found this example from web. Actually i understand what it does. I want to improve this example. What i want to do is print all values that return from this service but don't know what to do. Any guide or suggestion would be appriciated.

```
public void GetFeeds()
{
    WebClient wcXML = new WebClient();
    wcXML.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://cloud.tfl.gov.uk/TrackerNet/LineStatus"));
    wcXML.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(wClientUpdate);
}

/// <summary>        
/// Web Client Update Read Complete Event        
/// </summary>        
/// <param name="sender"></param>        
/// <param name="e"></param>        
void wClientUpdate(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        try
        {
            Stream Resultstream = e.Result;
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(Resultstream);
            XDocument xDocumentLive = XDocument.Load(reader);
            XNamespace ns = "http://webservices.lul.co.uk/";
            List<Feed> feedList = new List<Feed>();
            feedList.AddRange((from query in xDocumentLive.Element(ns + "ArrayOfLineStatus").Elements(ns + "LineStatus")
                           select new Feed
                           {
                               Name = (string)query.Element(ns + "Line").Attribute("Name").Value,
                               Description = (string)query.Element(ns + "Status").Attribute("Description").Value,
                               isActive = (string)query.Element(ns + "Status").Attribute("IsActive").Value
                           }).ToList());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Print where? please be more specific

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov To console

Comment: You want to print the `List<Feed>`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

To print out the `List<Feed>` to your `Output Window`, simply iterate it using `foreach`:

```
foreach (var feed in feedList)
{
   Debug.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Description: {1}, IsActive: {2}", feed.Name, feed.Description, feed.isActive)
}
```

Comment: I know i can use foreach, my problem is accessing that feedList

Comment: Why is it a problem? im not sure i understand what you need then

Comment: Do you know where to put this foreach code in order to see the output? That is the problem.

Comment: Yes, inside the `wClientUpdate` method. Why dont you use the Visual Studio debugger to see the values added to the list?

Comment: I have already tried that, but i don't see any output at the console.

Comment: Why dont you try using `Debug.WriteLine` instead. it will print out to the Output Window in VS

Comment: No change. Same result.

Comment: Could your list be empty?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57652/discussion-between-yuval-itzchakov-and-tartar).